# Is there a version of Robertson-Seymour's graph minor theorem for odd minors?

Tags: graph-theory

A graph $H$ is an *odd minor* of a graph $G$ if $H$ arises from $G$ by first deleting some vertices and edges and then contracting all edges in some edge cut.

Is it known that families of graphs that are characterized by a list of forbidden odd minors are characterized by a *finite* list of forbidden odd minors?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the well-quasi-ordering result of binary matroids would imply the well-quasi-ordering of graphs under odd minors. I also remember hearing Tony Huynh talking on structure of "group-labelled" graphs with a forbidden minors. Perhaps, though not everything is published, it must be known.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true, but the result is still being written up by Geelen, Gerards and Whittle as part of their [Matroid Minors Project](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jfgeelen/Research/research.html).

Also, for any fixed signed graph $H$, there is a polynomial-time algorithm to test if an input signed graph contains $H$ as a minor.  Together with the positive answer to your question, this implies that there is a polynomial-time algorithm to test for any minor-closed property of signed graphs.  See my [PhD thesis](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/4716) for the algorithm (which works more generally for any $\Gamma$-labelled graph, where $\Gamma$ is a fixed finite abelian group).

In the thesis there is also a mention of the well-quasi-ordering result that you want (Theorem 1.1.9).

Comment: How do minors of signed graphs relate to odd minors?  Is it obvious that the first includes the second as a special case?

Comment: If $H$ is an odd minor of $G$, then $(H, E(H))$ is a signed-minor of $(G, E(G))$.

Comment: But now that I think about it, this is not an if and only if since you do not allow re-signing and must contract *all* edges in an edge cut (and can only do this once).  Thus, my answer does not answer your question; I'll think about it some more.